# Azure Service Bus Client Connection Persistence

Tags: c#, azure, client, azureservicebus

I have below a basic wrapper around the Azure Service Bus code that we will be using within a worker role.  This `ServiceBusClient` will be instantiated each time the worker role is run; then used to access the queue until there are no remaining items left to enumerate through.

```
public class ServiceBusClient : IDisposable, IServiceBusClient
{
    private const int DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 120;

    private const string SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY = "service.bus.connection.string";

    private readonly MessagingFactory _messagingFactory;

    private readonly NamespaceManager _namespaceManager;

    private readonly QueueClient _queueClient;

    private readonly ISettingsManager _settingsManager;

    public ServiceBusClient(ISettingsManager settingsManager, string queueName)
    {
        _settingsManager = settingsManager;

        var connectionString = _settingsManager.GetSetting<string>(SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY);

        _namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        _messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

        _queueClient = GetOrCreateQueue(queueName);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _messagingFactory.Close();
    }

    public BrokeredMessage ReceiveTopMessage()
    {
        return _queueClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS));
    }

    public void SendMessage(object bodyObject)
    {
        var message = new BrokeredMessage(bodyObject);

        _queueClient.Send(message);
    }

    private QueueClient GetOrCreateQueue(string queueName)
    {
        var queue = !_namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName)
                        ? _namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueName)
                        : _namespaceManager.GetQueue(queueName);

        return _messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(queue.Path, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
    }

}
```

As you can see I initialise the `NamespaceManager`, `MessagingFactory` and `QueueClient` inside the constructor: they are then reused when calling `SendMessage()` and `ReceiveTopMessage()` with the connection closed using a `Dispose()` method.

My question is whether the approach I am using is *safe*; will keeping a single instance of the `QueueClient` open whilst a worker role enumerates through all the messages on the queue (A process which could keep the connection open for quite a while with a long wait between calls to `ReceiveTopMessage()`) work consistently without transient issues, or is it prudent to open and close the connection each time?

As an aside; how is the transient fault handling conducted in the Microsoft Service Bus code?  Is it conducted by default or do we need to implement the [Transient Fault Handling Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Transient-Fault-Handling-b209151f)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`QueueClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.aspx) uses a connection that is managed by the MessagingFactory object used to create it. It is recommended to reuse the same client object for multiple requests. As documented in [Best Practices for Performance Improvements Using Service Bus Brokered Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528527.aspx):

> The Service Bus enables clients to send and receive messages via two
>   protocols: the Service Bus client protocol, and HTTP. The Service Bus
>   client protocol is more efficient, because it maintains the connection
>   to the Service Bus service as long as the message factory exists. It
>   also implements batching and prefetching. The Service Bus client
>   protocol is available for .NET applications using the .NET managed
>   API.
>   (...)
>   Service Bus client objects, such as QueueClient or MessageSender, are
>   created through a MessagingFactory object, which also provides
>   internal management of connections. You should not close messaging
>   factories or queue, topic, and subscription clients after you send a
>   message, and then re-create them when you send the next message.
>   Closing a messaging factory deletes the connection to the Service Bus
>   service, and a new connection is established when recreating the
>   factory. Establishing a connection is an expensive operation that can
>   be avoided by re-using the same factory and client objects for
>   multiple operations.
>   (...)
>   All clients (senders in addition to receivers) that are created by the
>   same factory share one TCP connection.

Regarding transient fault handling, `QueueClient` has a [RetryPolicy property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagecliententity.retrypolicy.aspx) that that determines whether the request should be retried. There is also the [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934), which supersedes the Transient Fault Handling Framework.

Regarding message receive loops, there is guidance in [Implementing Reliable Message Receive Loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh851750.aspx). Microsoft has recognized that it's hard to implement a well-writen, resilient message receive loop, so they have introduced the [Event-Driven Message Programing Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn198643.aspx) as an alternative.

Comment: Excellent links thank you; I will be using [Implement Reliable Message Receive Loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh851750.aspx) in our wrapper.  If the `QueueClient` class does not open the connection; is this handled automatically when a method such as `.Receive()` is called?

Comment: I've clarified my answer with additional documentation about recommended usage pattern and which object handles the TCP connection.

Comment: My question are related to this question ill appreciate if you can have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512803/service-bus-singleton-connection-class 
@FernandoCorreia

Comment: Do you still think that we should .CloseAsync() when we are sending a message to a queue or a topic on the Microsoft.ServiceBus .Net Standart compatible NuGet package?